# Find the complex roots of the equation and do a check

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the complex roots of the equation and do a check:
$$ x^{2} + (2+i)x-1+7i=0 $$

What I've done:
$$D=b^2-4ac=(2+i)^2-4(-1+7i)=4+4i+4-28i=8-24i$$
$$\sqrt{8-24i}=\pm(\sqrt{(640-8)/2}+i(640+8)/2) = \sqrt{316}+18i$$

Here the wrong calculation. And then it will be necessary to calculate $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! How did you find the square roots of $8-24i$? Also: don't use the symbol $\sqrt$ for square roots of complex numbers: it is normally used for the non-negative square root of a non-negative real number.

Comment: $$8(1-3i)=16e^{-i60^\circ}$$

Comment: Actually $D=7-24i$ and $\sqrt D=\pm (4-3i)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying with 4 we get 
$$(2x+2+i)^2 =7-24i=(4-3i)^2$$

so $$2x =-2-i\pm(4-3i)$$ so $x_1=1-2i$ and $x_2 = -3+i$.

Answer (score 2):

All sorts of little errors.

$$D=(2+i)^2-4(-1+7i)=4+4i-1+4-28i=7-24i$$

You should now recognise $7, 24, 25$ as a pythagorean triple, or simply check that $$(7-24i)(7+24i)=25^2$$ whence (to use shorthand, as you have done) $\sqrt {7-24i}$ will be of the form $a+bi: a^2+b^2=25$ and you can spot $(4-3i)^2$

Answer (score 2):

You've made a small mistake in the calculation of your Discriminant :

$$D=(2+i)^2 -4(-1+7i)=7-24i$$

Then, the roots will be :

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-(2+i) \pm (7-24i)^{1/2}i }{2} = \frac{-2-i \pm [(-3i+4)^2]^{1/2}i}{2} $$

Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quadratic equation set to $0$, where $a=1$, $b=2+i$, and $c=-1+7i$. Plugging into the quadratic equation, we get:

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$=\frac{-(2+i)\pm\sqrt{(2+i)^2-4(1)(-1+7i)}}{2(1)}$$

From this point it’s basic arithmetic which I will leave as an exercise to the reader.